# Which data type is suitable for a date like 31-12-2014 in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have lots of data we want to store in Snowflake cloud but we could save the data into the snowflake due to date like 31-12-2014 which is given in an excel CSV file:

[image: check the image]]

I am trying:

```
"Shipment date" varchar(16777216),
"Shipment year" number(4),
```

which data type will be suitable for that purpose?

Comment: You store dates in a DATE datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the DATE data type, and you can easily insert your dates using TO_DATE function:

```
create table test_dates( d date );

insert into test_dates values (  TO_DATE( '31-12-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ));

select * from test_dates;
```

Date & Time Data Types: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html

TO_DATE: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html